# Primary key is not allowed in a has_and_belongs_to_many join table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have many-to-many linking table between two entities, datacenters and projects,
in legacy code.  I discovered, that it's really a one to many relationship.

As a first step to cleaning up the relationship, I wanted to put a unique index
on one of the fields.

Now I'm getting the following error:

Primary key is not allowed in a has_and_belongs_to_many join table (datacenters_projects).

I'm using Rails 2.3.8 running on ruby 1.8.7p174 and mysql  Ver 14.12 Distrib 5.0.77.

This is not a primary key, it's just a unique index.
I suppose it's a candidate key, but I haven't decided it is a primary key.

I don't know why mysql considers this to be a primary key.
I don't know why ActiveRecord would object to the linking table in a
has_and_belongs_to_many having a primary key.

But my real question is, "Is there any way I can put a unique index on 
one of the fields, without ActiveRecord giving me an error?"

Is there any way I can tell add_index that this is not a primary key?

Comment: could you show us your migration file where the problem occurs?

Comment: Legacy db/schema.rb:

  create_table "datacenters_projects", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
    t.integer "project_id",    :null => false
    t.integer "datacenter_id", :null => false
  end

  add_index "datacenters_projects", ["datacenter_id"], :name => "datacenters_projects_datacenters_fkey"
  add_index "datacenters_projects", ["project_id"], :name => "datacenters_projects_projects_fkey"

mine:

class AddOptimizationIndexes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_index "datacenters_projects", ["project_id"], :unique => true
  end
...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why that would fail. You should be able to get around it using SQL in your migration though, e.g:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("CREATE UNIQUE INDEX project_id_index ON datacenters_projects (project_id)")
```

Comment: That wasn't the problem.  The add_index did exactly what you said I should do.  The problem was that I had legacy code using has_and_belongs_to_many, and has_and_belongs_to_many, in the version of Rails we were using would give an error if the table had an :id field.  Later versions of rails use has_many :through, which allows :id fields in the table.

Comment: Your question was "Is there any way I can put a unique index on one of the fields, without ActiveRecord giving me an error?" which I answered. If you're marking your answer as correct, I'd change your question, as the accepted answer doesn't answer this question :)

Comment: If I create the index as you said, the has_and_belongs_to_many will still give the error.  The problem wasn't an error in the migration.

Comment: I'll vote up your answer because you did answer if I could tell add_index it was not a primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to

```
has_many :through => ...
```

Ref: [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)